# Problema con upload de archivos en PHP

Tags: php, fileupload

Tengo un problema a la hora de realizar la subida de archivos a través de un formulario en PHP. Se envían archivos de tamaño pequeño como 400 KB sin problema, pero si envío un archivo de 900 KB (probando incluso un único archivo), el navegador me muestra el error PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR (en el caso de Firefox). He revisado la configuración en el php.ini y las variables que intervienen en el proceso de envío tienen valores correctos

```
upload_max_size= 8M;

post_max_size= 8M;

memory_limit= 8M;

max_execution_time= 300;
```

también he probado a ejecutarlo en otros navegadores. En todos sucede lo mismo, se corta la comunicación con el servidor cuando el archivo supera un tamaño (mucho más bajo del especificado en el php.ini). Alguien sabe por qué puede suceder esto?
Aunque intente ejecutar un var_dump($_FILES) no puedo ver el resultado porque no se muestra la página

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_FILES);` y agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit] para ver si muestra más información sobre el tipo de error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado, revisé los logs del servidor en httpd. Aparecia el siguiente error:
"Requested content-length of 1646786 is larger than the configured limit of 524288, referer: https://dirección_de_página".
Para aumentar el tamaño hay que ir al archivo php.conf y aumentar el valor en   LimitRequestBody. Hecho esto es necesario reiniciar el servicio httpd.